# MouseMotionListener Is not doing what its supposed to?

Tags: java, mousemotionlistener

This code is kind of a mess. Im trying to prevent the mouse from going outside the red. MouseMotionListener is not working. Ive added The Listener, implemented it. When I try to use `e.getX()`Nothing shows up! Here is the code: Any help is good!

Class MazeMouse

```
public class MazeMouse extends JPanel implements ActionListener, MouseMotionListener {
    JButton d,k;
    JLabel f;
    int button = 0;
    
    
    MazeMouse(){
           addMouseMotionListener(this);  
        setBackground(Color.black);
        
        f= new JLabel("                                        ");
        k = new JButton("Press To Finish");
        d = new JButton("Press To Begin");
        add(d);
        add(f);
    add(k);

        
k.addActionListener(this);  
          d.addActionListener(this);
    }
    
    
    @Override

    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    
       
           if(button == 1) {
                 g2.setColor(Color.red);
                
                 //start Rect
                 g2.fillRect(150,0,200,50);
                //below start
                g2.fillRect(150, 50, 50, 200);
                //finish Rect
               g2.fillRect(450, 0, 200, 50);
               //below finish
               g2.fillRect(600,50,50,200);
               //really tiny line
               g2.fillRect(150, 250, 500, 1);
             
           }
            
        
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
 if(e.getSource()==d)
 {      
     button++;
     d.setEnabled(false);
     repaint();
 }
 
 
 if(e.getSource()==k) {
    setBackground(Color.green);
 }
        
    }


    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }


    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        e.getX();
        if(button ==1) {
            if(e.getX() < 150 && e.getX() > 350 ) {
                System.out.println("Game Over");
            }
            }
        
    }

    
    
}
```

And MM

```
public class MM {
    JFrame f;    
    MazeMouse p; 

  
    int button = 0;
    public MM(){    
        
        f = new JFrame(); 
        Container c = f.getContentPane();    
                c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());   
              
    
                
                p = new MazeMouse();   
        c.add(p); 
        
        
        f.setSize(800,800);    
        f.setVisible(true);    
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
    
    
    
    }
    public static void main(String args[ ]){    
        MM t = new MM();     
    }
    
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `When I try to use e.getX()Nothing shows up!` - basic debuggin rule is to display the value of the e.getX() method BEFORE the if statement. How do you know when the  if statement is  true? `if(e.getX() < 150 && e.getX() > 350 )` - how can the mouse point be < 150 AND > 350 at the same time?

Comment: `if(e.getX() < 150 && e.getX() > 350 )` is supposed to restrict where the mouse goes. Basically a line where the mouse "cannot be"

Comment: You still miss the point! You can't use an AND condition because those two conditions can NEVER happen at the same time. In any case, a MousteLisener can't prevent the mouse from moving. It only generates an event when the mouse moves. So you get the event AFTER the mouse has already moved.